# How to add webpart to blog post?

Tags: web-part, web-part-gallery

The idea is to use SharePoint Blog site as news site. Every new post has it's own pictures which users must see.

I found a great webpart (Mirata Picture Gallery) for displaying images from Photos blog library where I can specify library name and folder name which I want to show.

The question is: How I can add this webpart to be unique to every blog post?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think that the OOTB wiki pages will be better then blog. If I'm not wrong, in this case you can insert your web part in any part of the page.

Comment: I need to have comment possibility on every post we anounce so wiki site as our news site will not suite.

Comment: @DanielBadanjak, you can coppy wiki page layout, rename it and add comments to this layout. There are several options you can create your own controls or use something like [this](http://disqus.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Open your post, goto the Site Actions menu, then Edit Page. You can then add web parts just like any other web part page.

Comment: I thought that too :) but the problem is that the same webpart instance is then on every blog post then. I need different webpart instances for every blog post.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways; create your own Site Template or use a code solution. Depending on your site (and if you already have sites deployed), code is the easiest way to do it; adding it as a 'stapler' event handler that will do the work when a site is created.

The process is simple: You simply open the site, get a reference to the web part (from the library), crack open the Post.aspx and insert the web part in the zone of your choice.

If interested, I'll post code solution.

David Sterling
davidmsterling.blogspot.com
www.sterling-consulting.com
www.sharepoint-blog.com

Comment: Just so you have it, I've posted the code that'll save your a bunch of time: http://userratingwebpart.codeplex.com/
http://addratingstoblogsite.codeplex.com/

Comment: FYI - you can modify the AddRatingsToBlogSite to do exactly what you want to - thank me later!

Comment: Hello, I managed to insert my Mirata Picture Gallery through Add Ratings To Blogsite solution but the problem is still same as I manually added web part to Blog Post page which @ng93 suggested. If I add webpart to post.aspx every post will have the same gallery including new ones. Maybe there is different blog post gallery sollution?